# Call a function defined in a object

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2

There is a ‘card’ object with a ‘func’ property which is a function. I want to pass this object,‘card’, to another component and call it’s function from second component.

first component:

`>template> <second-component :card="card"> </second-component> </template>`

and script:

`>script>data: () => ({ card: {caption: 'cap',func: function () { console.log('here')} }}) </script>`

second component:

`>div> @click="clicked"</div>`

script:

`props: ['card' ], methods: { clicked() {this.card.func} }`

Why it does nothing? How can i call that function from second component?

`

Comment: share live demo , and what error / output you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get error. but doesn't  call that function @user2486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not executing the function

```
this.card.func()
```

Comment: @HoseinPanahi : If it fixed your problem , Consider to accept this answer.